# Processing SSAS cube fast compared to processing cube in

Tags: sql, ssis, ssas, sql-server-2019

I have upgraded to SQL 2019 from SQL 2016.

Within my SSIS package I process a cube (dimensions and then partitions) this takes a long time to process and it seems that the processing hardly uses any memory or CPU when processing through SSIS. This take approximately 60 minutes plus.

When I process the cube on the server via management studio (or even via XMLA script) - right click and process (on the same server as the database and SSIS service), the process takes 20 minutes to run and I can see the memory and CPU increase.

Why is it that the cube processing is slow when running in SSIS. Also, the CPU never gets above 5% -  however when running manually it gets up to 25%.

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 1):

Well, to answer your first question - why processing SSAS cube from SSIS component is slower - you have to capture XMLA command generated by SSIS component and compare it with XMLA generated by SSMS. Suspect command generated by SSIS is sub-optimal.
I prefer to capture XMLA processing command from SSMS (from Process window - choose Script - Clipboard), store it into a string variable and then run it in SSIS as an XMLA command. Thus you get better control of what exactly you are executing against SSAS server.